How to estimate price elasticity of supply for beef
I tried to compare the price elasticity of demand and supply for beef. Elasticity of demand can be obtained from a study, but I cannot find anything giving the elasticity of demand. I wonder if there's any good sources or ways to estimate this quantity in a relatively simple way.

Your second sentence is self-contradictory.
